# When to use __str___ method inside Django model?

Tags: python, sql, django, django-models, jinja2

I have created a Django model with the following attributes.

```
class Info(models.Model):
    number = models.IntegerField()
    ID = models.IntegerField()
    reading = models.IntegerField()
    date = models.DateField()
```

I would like to make it so that when a user searches for an 'ID' or 'number' from the database, they are shown the date and reading. Here is my search results code in views.py:

```
class SearchResultsView(ListView):
    model = Info
    template_name = 'search_results.html'

    def get_queryset(self): 
        query = self.request.GET.get('q')
        reading_list = Info.objects.filter(
            Q(ID__icontains=query) | Q(number__icontains=query)
        )
        return reading_list
```

And here is my search_results.html template:

```
<h1>Search Results</h1>

<ul>
  {% for reading in reading_list %}
    <li>
      {{ reading.reading }}, {{ reading.date }}
    </li>
  {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

I am a little confused as to whether I should include a '**str**' method in my model. Will the app be able to print the date and reading using just this code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your current settings, there is no need to add a `__str__` function in your model because you are using instance's fields rather than instance itself.

However, if there are any references to the instance itself, e.g. a foreign key to this model or you just want to check the instance itself, adding a `__str__` function will increase the readability. You can check [the `__str__` documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/instances/#str) for details.

Without `__str__` field, if you have an Info instance, you will have:
`<Info: Info object (1)>`. After adding a `__str___` function and return str(id) for example, you will see `<Info: 1>`.

It would be great to have a CharField(e.g. `description = models.CharField()`) in your Info model if you want to add the `__str__` function. Then the representation of this object would be `<Info: Good Reading>`

Answer (score 0):

Whenever an instance of model is created in Django, it displays the object as ModelName Object(1).to make changes to your Django model using this

```
def __str__(self): 
    return str(self.id) #if its integer, make it str
    return self.name #if its already str. you dont make it str
```

it changes the display name from ModelName Object(1) to field name of `def __str__(self):` in your admin panel.
**and one thing `def __str__(self)` for python 3 and `def __unicode__(self):` for python 2**